# XPages Extension Library Dialog will not allow entry in a RichText Control

Tags: dialog, xpages, xpages-extlib

I have a dialog that I call from within an XPage. This dialog amongst other things contains a RichText Control. The control displays correctly but will not allow me to enter any text into the control. I can insert an image from the menu, but I can not seem to get focus with the mouse to enter text. I have looked through the properties but everything looks OK.
Any thought or ideas that I might check?

Comment: Besides Per's solution you might want to check your interaction pattern. Dialog boxes belong to classical desktop applications. I would try to avoid them in web applications - they certainly won't work well in a fluid layout on a small device. Use the 'progressive disclosure' or the 'wizard' pattern instead

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'progressive disclosure' or 'wizard' pattern

Comment: These interaction patterns alter the main display to show or hide required input information instead of popups. So interaction happens entirely on the page. When used with navigation buttons previous/next (when appropriate) it is also called wizard pattern. http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_disclosure insight is always just a Google away

Answer (score 3):

I made a very simple test and have no issues entering text in the rich text control:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoDocument var="document1"></xp:dominoDocument>
    </xp:this.data>

    <xp:button value="Label" id="button1">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:getComponent("InputDialog").show()}]]></xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>

    <xe:dialog id="InputDialog">
        <xp:inputRichText id="inputRichText1" value="#{document1.Body}"></xp:inputRichText>
    </xe:dialog>
</xp:view>
```

I am running Domino 9.0.1 (and tested using Chrome).

Check the browser console for any errors and also try testing in a new nsf using my example above.

Comment: From what I found out is that it is a bug in 9.0 and is fixed in 9.0.1 which is a real pain in the butt, because I can not force all my clients to upgrade to 9.0.1 to make my application work. It would appear that I will need to make the control an Edit Box but I really don't want to. Appears to be no hot fix.